# Is the subset of a closed set closed?

Tags: general-topology

Question: Is the subset of a closed set closed ?
Answer: I think it is because let $R$ be the set of the real number system. Any subset of it is a closed set.
If not, I would like to know a counterexample

Comment: For instance, one of the absurdly numerous non-closed subsets of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: I am not able to post question.. can anyone please tell me wat is the problem

Comment: I love how the moderator has tried to answer the question. xD

Answer (score 5):

In $\Bbb{R},$ the interval $(0,1)$ is not closed and $(0,1)\subset[0,1].$